# Is "Ich freue mich, Sie als meinen Freund zu haben" correct?

Tags: preposition, dative

I saw

> I'm happy to have you as my friend.

being translated as

> Ich freue mich, Sie als meinen Freund zu haben.

But I thought since *meinen* comes after the preposition *als*, it should be *meinem* (i.e. masculine dative form). I think the direct object of *haben* is *Sie*, and *als meinen Freund* being just an adverbial phrase. Am I wrong?

Comment: Similar: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35442/why-is-the-adjective-ending-of-the-accusative-case-used-in-this-sentence-after

Comment: Better: *Ich freue mich, Sie zum Freund zu haben.*

Comment: If you are friends, the relationship should be so close that you don't have to adress him/her the polite way. You should not need "Sie" anymore but can use: "Ich freue mich, dich zum Freund zu haben."

Comment: Good news, you can drop "meinen" and the problem just disappears. :) (And there's no need for using "zum"; but of course it's correct, too.)

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier - Sometimes one has as a friend an older person whom we must address with *Sie*.

Comment: Short alternatives: _»Gut/Schön, dass du mein[e] Freund[in] bist.«_ and _»Gut/Schön, dich als Freund[in] zu haben.«_

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier There is an important semantic difference between *Freund* and *friend*. *Friend*  can be translated as either *Freund* or *Bekannte*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are wrong. The preposistion *als* demands accusative case in this case, since "Sie" is accusative as well. So

> Ich freue mich, Sie als meinen Freund zu haben.

is correct and

> *Ich freue mich, Sie als meine**m** Freund zu haben.

would be wrong.

---

Though the sentence is correct in respect to grammar, it is stylistically flawed, as others alread stated in the comments. In most cases you would not call a friend "Sie", but "Du", so

> Ich freue mich, Dich als meinen Freund zu haben.

woul be more appropriate.

Other variants sound more natural, for instance

> Ich freue mich, dich zum Freund zu haben.
>
> Ich freue mich, dass du mein Freund bist.

Comment: Even more natural: ***Ich bin froh***, dass du mein Freund bist*.

Comment: It is not a stylistic flaw to be old-fashioned.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. Deutsch sounds cool! :)

Answer (score 1):

You call your fiends "Sie"?

In any case, the "meinen" seems superfluous (but correct, as opposed to "meinem", which would be wrong; "als" is not being used for comparison here).

"Ich freue mich, Dich als Freund zu haben".  But, as others have commented, ""Ich freue mich, Dich zum Freund zu haben" sound sbetter.

Comment: Das beantwortet so manche Frage, nur nicht die gestellte.